# Форматированный вывод в консоль C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Имеется массив структур **device** следующего вида:

```
struct device {
    unsigned int number;
    char name[20];
    unsigned int year;
    double cost;
};
```

Необходимо написать функцию которая выводит шапку  и информацию об устройствах.

Пример:

```
|№  |Код  |Имя       |Год производства  |Цена   |
|1  |1234 |abcdefsdf |2019              |20.19  |
|2  |4321 |asdfa     |2017              |999.99 |
```

В ходе многочасовых поисков я пришел к следующему коду:

```
void printAll(device* d) {

    cout << left << setw(3) << "|№";

    cout << left << setw(11) << "|Код";

    cout << left << setw(21) << "|Имя";

    cout << left << setw(5) << "|Год";

    cout << left << setw(10) << "|Цена";

    cout << right << "|\n\n";

    for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++) {

        cout << left << setw(3) << "|" << i+1;

        cout << left << setw(11) << "|" << d[i].number;

        cout << left << setw(21) << "|" << d[i].name;

        cout << left << setw(5) << "|" << d[i].year;

        cout << left << setw(10) << "|" << d[i].cost;

        cout << right << "|\n" ;
    }
}
```

Вывод:

[image: Вывод]

Я понимаю что он вкрай неправильный, но не могу понять что же я сделал не так (хотя проще будет сказать что я сделал ТАК).

Comment: Просто ознакомьтесь с возможностями [<iomanip>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip)

Comment: Код стал короче и читабильнее, но вывод по прежнему не такой как должен быть

Comment: setw() работает только на один следующий вывод. Поменяйте его местами с "|" и уменьшите на единицу везде в setw() в цикле(так как "|" выводится отдельно, в отличии от шапки)

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon СПАСИБО!
Весь день с этим промучался, а хватило лишь одного короткого (но чертовски полезного) комментария!